# will_paginate render all the values if page and per_page is not sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, will-paginate

I use will_paginate to get the values in paging. consider the example

```
if params[:page] || params[:per_page]
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page 
    => params[:per_page]).all(:order => 'id ASC')
else
    @users = User.all(:order => 'id ASC')
end

format.json {
 render json: 
      {:users => @users, :current_page => @users.current_page, 
       :total_pages => @users.total_pages, 
       :total_entries => @users.total_entries
      }
}
```

if i did not send any parameter`( params[:page] or params[:per_page] )` then it shows

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `current_page' for #<Array:0x000002345ab655>)
```

Comment: Where is your pagination for the else part ?

Comment: if i add pagination in the else part then how can i fetch all the entries? won't it give only few entries by default

Comment: why you think that `params[:page]` can be null ? It will be null when something went wrong. If there are less entries then the `params[:page]`, it will give them in a single page. Your else part is not using pagination and in json you are defining `current_page` for it which is causing exception.

Comment: ok say if i have 100 entries and i do not know how many entries are present then if i send page=1 then it would send me only few entries in the page 1. So i have to go again to the next page. Is there is something like getting all using something like .paginate(all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => User.count)
```

**NOTE:**

It will put all the users in one page and thus it will obstruct the significance of
          Pagination. But if this is all you want, it is for you.

Comment: if i simply use .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page 
    => params[:per_page]) and if i did not send any value then how many value does it take by default?

Comment: The default is `30`. Source - https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation

Comment: Weirdly this returns 0 for me. I checked the query and it sets LIMIT and OFFSET both to max records. Any suggestions?